# SQL select Employees with Hire Status on specified date from history table

Tags: sql, select

I have an Employees table and an EmploymentHistory table that captures changes to their employment status. I want to be able to select a list of all employees that had a "hired" status for a given date (e.g. 04/02/2013, which would only yield John Smith below).

```
Employees       
employeeId    lastName    firstName
1             Smith       John
2             Doe         Jane
3             Carson      Mike

EmployeeHistory         
employeeHistoryId   employeeId    employmentStatus    transactionDate
1                   1             Hired               3/1/2013
2                   2             Candidate           4/1/2013
3                   2             Not Hired           4/5/2013
4                   3             Candidate           1/1/2013
5                   3             Hired               1/3/2013
6                   3             Terminated          2/15/2013
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports `row_number()`, you can use it to find the last row per employee before a particular date.  For example:

```
select  *
from    Employees e
join    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by employeeId
                    order by transactionDate desc) as rn
        ,       employeeId
        ,       employmentStatus
        from    EmployeeHistory
        where   transactionDate < '2013-04-02'
        ) h
on      e.EmployeeId = h.EmployeeId
        and h.rn = 1 -- Only last row
where   h.employmentStatus = 'Hired'
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a7dc/1/0)